# Java Script Validation for file uploading

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I got stuck in JavaScript validation in product adding form.

In that page I have file upload control to upload product image. I am not getting how to validate that using JavaScript.

If image is not uploaded to that control I want to display `Upload Image` message in Label.

How to accomplish this? Please help me.

**The script I have written is:**

```
var fileup = document.getElementById('<%=FileUploadImg.ClientID %>').value;
if (fileup == "") 
{
   document.getElementById("lblFileUploadImg").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>
   Upload Image File</font>";

   document.getElementById('<%=FileUploadImg.ClientID %>').focus();
   return false;
} 
else 
{
    document.getElementById("lblFileUploadImg").innerHTML = "";
}
```

**The control I have used is:**

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadImg" runat="server" Width="217px" Height="20px" />
 <asp:Label ID="lblFileUploadImg" runat="server" >
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could simply do this:

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
    if(this.files[0].size>...){
        alert('File is too big');
    };

});
```

maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
$("input:file").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        var ul_file = $(this).val();
        var extension = ul_file.substr((ul_file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
        var accepted_file_endings = ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif", "tif", "png"];
        extension = extension.toLowerCase()
        if ($.inArray(extension, accepted_file_endings) !== -1) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get validate file uploading using JavaScript like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var uploadcontrol = document.getElementById('<%=FileUploadImg.ClientID%>').value;

            //Regular Expression for fileupload control.
            var reg = /(.doc|.docx|.pdf)$/i;

            if (uploadcontrol.length > 0)
            {
                //Checks with the control value.
                if (reg.test(uploadcontrol))
                {
                    document.getElementById('<%=lblFileUploadImg.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "<font color='green'>Upload Image File</font>";
                    return true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    //If the condition not satisfied shows error message.
                    document.getElementById('<%=lblFileUploadImg.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "Error while upload image";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } //End of function validate.
    </script>


<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadImg" runat="server" Width="217px" Height="20px" />
<asp:Label ID="lblFileUploadImg" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Upload" ID="btnupload" onclientclick="return validate();"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function Validate() {
            var fileup = document.getElementById('<%=FileUploadImg.ClientID %>').value;
            if (fileup == "") {
                document.getElementById('<%=lblFileUploadImg.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "<font color='red'>Upload Image File</font>";

                document.getElementById('<%=FileUploadImg.ClientID %>').focus();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%=lblFileUploadImg.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadImg" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblFileUploadImg" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return Validate();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```